# UWP : Share from a sharetarget

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I've made a (kind of) image editor app that is a ShareTarget (obviously for images).
This app can also share its content to other apps.

I've got two issues :

The first one appears when my app is called as a sharetarget by another app and then I want to share my app content.

- On W10, it works just fine
- On W10M (Creator Update & release2 insider builds) : the ShowShareUI() does nothing. In fact, the event "DataTransferManager_DataRequested" is not even raised...

I reproduced this behaviour on another image editor app on W10M (Phototastic) with success. So, it seems W10M can't manage two apps sharing content consecutively... Could you think of a workaround ?

The other issue is with the size of my app window on W10. As a sharetarget, the app has no minimize/maximize buttons. How to have my app window behave normally ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I changed the place where I declare the event to the constructor of the page, to the OnNavigatedTo, or to the OnLoaded, and on mobile, when the app is already on "sharetarget mode", the ShareUI is not displayed.

Comment: I thinked about a workaround :
I changed the way my app treats ShareTarget calls => instead of treating the file received, I save it on the temp storage, then launch my app from the "sharetarget mode" version using a launcher and get the fileactivated event to treat the temp file. But I've got others issues now ^^

Any idea would be welcome :)

Comment: Did you mean, you want App A share source with App B and App B as a share target at the same time share source with App C?

Comment: I'll be more explicit, sorry :)
App A (ex : Photos app) shares content to App B (my app), which is a light photo editor. Then, from App B, I want to share the edited pic to App C (ex : messaging).

On W10 Desktop, it works just fine. On W10M, it doesn't :
- on emulator and insider (release 2) builds, the call to ShowShareUI() is ignored by the system (nothing happens)
- on a 930 with updated Creator Update, the app crashes on my RenderAsync() call with an unhandled exception in the KernelBase.dll / Windows.UI.Xaml.dll.

Comment: I've tried to develop an helper :
- App A shares to my helper (App B)
- App B then launch the App C
- App C can share to App D.

With the helper in the middle, it works OK on Insider builds but it still crashes on the 930.

Comment: I finished setting an info pop-up on W10M saying that sharing from a sharetarget is not possible on this platform. And as W10M is now dead, I Don't hope to see this behaviour modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finished setting an info pop-up on W10M saying that sharing from a sharetarget is not possible on this platform. And as W10M is now dead, I Don't hope to see this behaviour modified.